# How to export Blender model with animation & materials to Maya

Tags: export, import

I made a rigged box with an animation. I want to export it and use it in a Maya scene. Whenever I export it the box is all merged together and it doesn't display either the material, the animation, or the armature. Can someone please tell me how to properly export the model? should I use fbx or obj and what settings should I have?

I would appreciate any kind of help, thank you

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 0):

I converted the materials to a base map and exported the box to .fbx because I needed the joints and did the animation all over again. One of my friends told me that the easiest way to export animations from blender is with Alembics, however, this format doesn’t export rigs.